# Detect Sub-Object in a image

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

Currently, I am reading the literature for object detection with deepl learning algorithms, and i founded many methods like "Fast-CNN, Faster-RCNN, YOLO9000", but I have a question, does he exist a method that can detect object and sub-object for example "we detect a person and his hand, his feet and so on ..."

Please if anyone know something about that please advice me

"I use Tensorflow for my implementation"

Thanks

Comment: I was also interested in understanding just how granular the prediction from YOLO9000 can get - because what I am getting right now doesn't appear to be detecting individual "faces", "hands" etc. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/darknet/UzaJNGg0pjo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such methods do exist! Note that detecting the class of an object from an image using neural networks is "easier" than detecting exactly what body part is where. This would require you to have a model for each body part, and an algorithm that determines where this body part is located (not an easy task!).

One example of a paper from 2014 that proposes a model is this one: http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Chen_Detect_What_You_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf . Note that there are many approaches to this problem, so you should do a bit of literature study to find the one that best suits your problem!

Good luck!